# Find: Cannot chdir to directory error message after deleting directories

Tags: bash, shell, unix, automation

I am working on a project to automatically delete specific directories which are older than a day. I have got the following piece of code working:

```
find Directory/ -type d -name "Directory.To.Delete.*" -mtime +1 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

It runs fine and deletes the directory (and contents) as expected, however it always ends with an error:

```
find: cannot chdir to Directory/ : No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to run this code without facing this error? I don't understand why this code is trying to chdir after deleting the directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `-prune` before `-exec`; that will stop `find` from entering matches directories:

```
.... -mtime +1 -prune -exec ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Add -depth before -type d will also stop find from entering matched directories.

```
# mkdir 1
# mkdir 2
# touch -d yesterday 1
# find . -depth -type d -mtime +0 -exec rm -rf {} \;
# ls
2
```

From man find:

```
   -prune True;  if  the file is a directory, do not descend into it. If -depth is given, false; no effect.  Because -delete implies -depth, you cannot usefully use -prune and -delete together.
```